# Spring Consul app crashes when there is no agent up

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

We have started to explore [Spring Cloud Consul](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/spring-cloud-consul.html) and we see that if the Consul agent is down the app crashes when it started... is it the expected behavior? we have expected that the app will wait to the agent to be up and retry at least several times or at least that this behavior will be configurable...

Also if the agent was up at start it successfully registers the service in the catalog but if at some point the agent went down even for several seconds the app will fail to talk the agent and will not retry to talk with the agent again... This cause a scenario that the app is up but it is no longer talking to the agent again we would expect a retry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an open [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/81) that we are tracking.

Comment: so does it mean that you are going to implement this functionality in the future? when do you estimate it will be released?

Comment: I plan to. There's no timeframe at the moment. The good thing is, we've already done this with Spring Cloud Config Client and can port the functionality. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#config-client-retry